# Why is emplace_back() behaving like this?

Tags: c++

1. Why does ~Base() get called immediately after the call to emplace_back()
2. Why is sayHello() accessible after the destructor call
3. Why does ~Base() get called again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
    private:

        static int m_count;

    public:

        Base()
        {
            std::cout << " Base created. Count = " << ++m_count << std::endl;
        }

        ~Base()
        {
            std::cout << " Base destroyed. Count = " << --m_count << std::endl;
        }

        void sayHello() const
        {
            std::cout << " Base says hello" << std::endl;
        }
};

int Base::m_count = 0;

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector< Base > vBase;

        vBase.emplace_back ( Base() );  // <- Why does ~Base() get called here

        vBase[0].sayHello(); // <- Why is this function accessible after call to dtor
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output...

```
Base created. Count = 1  
Base destroyed. Count = 0  
Base says hello
Base destroyed. Count = -1
```

Comment: You should get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn from that. It will surely mention copy constructors and the Rule of Three.

Comment: Note: since you defined `~Base()`, this suppresses implicit generation of the move-constructor  (and may also suppress copy-constructor in future versions of the language). You probably want to define the move-constructor, and either default it, or make it `noexcept`.

Comment: You still didn't accept any answer. That's not nice. [SO: What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

In the call `vBase.emplace_back ( Base() );` you first create a `Base` object. The vector creates another `Base` in place and the resources owned by the first `Base` are then moved into the new one. The first base is then deleted. Inside your vector you now have a moved constructed `Base` which is why the call to `sayHello()` works.

What you probably want to do is to let `emplace_back` actually construct the object, in place without creating a temporary object manually. You do that by only supplying the arguments needed to construct a `Base`. Like so:

```
vBase.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the point of emplace. Emplace functions construct the object in-place from the given arguments, as opposed to e.g. `push_back` which copy-constructs it from a pre-existing object. You should have written `vBase.emplace_back()` which constructs the object inside the vector in-place with no constructor arguments (i.e. default constructed).

As it stands you're effectively default constructing a `Base` object via `Base()`, passing it to emplace, which calls the constructor taking a `Base` object (i.e. the move constructor), copying it, and then the original i.e. the `Base()` object is destroyed.

Its copy is still in the vector, which is why you can still access it. What was destroyed was the temporary. The second destructor call is the copy being destroyed when the vector goes out of scope.

So you're basically just doing the same thing as `push_back`.

Answer (score 8):

You're not including the objects created by move and copy constructors in your counter, nor are you logging the calls. If you make changes to your logging to fix the Rule of Three/Five violation, you'll see this:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

/// noisy
///
/// A class logs all of the calls to Big Five and the default constructor
/// The name of the template parameter, received as if by call
/// to `typeid(T).name()`, is displayed in the logs.
template<typename T>
struct noisy
{
    noisy& operator=(noisy&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "MOVE ASSIGNMENT<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ", other = " << &other << ")\n"; return *this; }
    noisy& operator=(const noisy& other) { std::cout << "COPY ASSIGNMENT<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ", other = " << &other << ")\n"; return *this; }
    noisy(const noisy& other) { std::cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ", other = " << &other << ")\n"; }
    noisy(noisy&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "MOVE CONSTRUCTOR<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ", other = " << &other << ")\n"; }
    ~noisy() { std::cout << "DESTRUCTOR<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ")\n"; }
    noisy() { std::cout << "CONSTRUCTOR<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(this = " << this << ")\n"; }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base : public noisy<Base>
{
    public:

        void sayHello() const
        {
            std::cout << "Base says hello" << "(this = " << this << ")" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector< Base > vBase;

        vBase.emplace_back ( Base() );  // <- Why does ~Base() get called here

        vBase[0].sayHello(); // <- Why is this function accessible after call to dtor
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
CONSTRUCTOR<4Base>(this = 0x7fff300b580f)
MOVE CONSTRUCTOR<4Base>(this = 0x18a6c30, other = 0x7fff300b580f)
DESTRUCTOR<4Base>(this = 0x7fff300b580f)
Base says hello(this = 0x18a6c30)
DESTRUCTOR<4Base>(this = 0x18a6c30)
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a99d01d1f2265349)</kbd>

Comment: That noisy template is a great idea. Had I used it initially, I would have answered my own question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dom If this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer (there is a grayed-out checkbox to the left).