# Why there is more `deconstructor` calls than `constructor` calls?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to study C++ using `stl`, I noticed that there are more `deconstruct` calls than `construct` calls, I am wondering whether I missed anything.

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const Person &p) {
    os << p.name << endl;
    return os;
  }
  string name;

public:
  Person() {
    cout << "created " << this->name << endl;
  };
  Person(string name):
    name{name} {
      cout << "created " << this->name << endl;
    }
  ~Person() {
    cout << "deconstructor " << this->name << endl;
  }
  bool operator<(const Person &rhs) const {
    return this->name < rhs.name;
  }

  bool operator==(const Person &rhs) const {
    return (this->name == rhs.name);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<Person> vec {{"test1"}, {"test2"}};
    Person p {"test2"};
    vector<Person>::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), p);
    Person p2 {"test3"};
    vec.insert(it, p2);
    for (auto &p : vec) {
      cout << p;
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
created test1
created test2
deconstructor test2
deconstructor test1
created test2
created test3
deconstructor test2
deconstructor test1
test1
test3
test2
deconstructor test3
deconstructor test2
deconstructor test2
deconstructor test3
deconstructor test1
```

`test1` has been deconstructed three times, but only created once.

Any explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799469/why-is-emplace-back-behaving-like-this/56799500#56799500) and the corresponding question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to create a copy constructor.

```
Person(const Person &p): name{p.name} {
    cout << "created " << this->name << endl;
}
```

Comment: One should also implement the move constructor, see the answer it the merged to question