# Object destructor kept being called when multithreading, yet the object is not out of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, c++11, c++14

I am not sure why even I called the object's member function, even it is still in it's scope, the destructor is still called.
A simple example is shown as below:

```cpp
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
class Obj1
{
private:

public:
    ~Obj1();
    void testFunc();
};

Obj1::~Obj1()
{
    std::cout<<"destory\n";
}
void Obj1::testFunc(){
    std::cout<<"testfun\n";
}
```

```cpp
#include "Obj1.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    Obj1 obj1 = Obj1();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        std::thread th =  std::thread(&Obj1::testFunc,obj1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout<<"we wait\n";
    }
}
```

When I tried to run it, I can see the output:

```
destory
testfun
destory
we wait
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I wonder why obj1 is destroyed every time the thread ends?
p.s. the reason for that 1s delay is because this is used in a realtime system, the main loop has a lower frequency, the task will be done before the next loop.

Comment: Just FYI. this is overkill: `Obj1 obj1 = Obj1();`  should simply be `Obj1 obj1;`. Second, thread args are by-value (so in your case, copied). If you want to reference the same object, then use a ref-wrapper. I'd use the address of obj1.

Comment: Why do you sleep for 1s ? To allow the thread to finish work? Bad practise. Also you don't call th.join() or th.detach();

Comment: You're copying the object and you don't know it, because you're not logging all the calls to Big Five (only the destructor). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799469/why-is-emplace-back-behaving-like-this/56799500#56799500 and here's [what happens when you fix the logging](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b368459f57728d4)

Comment: @WhozCraig std::ref(obj1) ???

Comment: @HAOLEE for member fn ptrs, its going to take an obj address or a bind setup. the former is in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two biggest problems in your code:

- You're making copies for each `std::thread` you launch.
- You're not waiting for your threads to terminate.

A `std::thread` requires a callable, and if required, appropriate arguments. In your case the callable is pointer-to-member-function, which requires an object instance or address (`std::thread` will use either). You're giving it the former by way of making *copies* of `obj1`. If the intent is for *all* threads to access the *same* object, you should pass the address instead.

And then wait for the threads to terminate, of course

**Code** (with added messaging to detect copy-construction)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class Obj1
{
public:
    Obj1() { std::cout << "construct\n"; }
    Obj1(const Obj1&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    ~Obj1() { std::cout << "destroy\n"; }

    void testFunc();
};

void Obj1::testFunc() {
    std::cout << "testfun\n";
}

int main()
{
    Obj1 obj1;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(&Obj1::testFunc, &obj1); // <<== HERE

    for (auto& t : threads)
        t.join();
}
```

**Output** (can vary)

```
construct
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
testfun
destroy
```

Comment: A similar sample (with a little bit more noise): [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6a20de1c5e83d5a).